# CSS media query for whether a physical keyboard is attached

Tags: css, keyboard, media-queries

Suppose I have a site with keyboard shortcuts, where I want to display said keyboard shortcuts visually as part of whatever element they apply to.

On a touch interface, especially a phone, I don't want to bother because:

1. nobody would use a soft-keyboard this way even if they could
2. the visual display of the keyboard shortcut takes up valuable real-estate
3. it's perhaps confusing, or at least inelegant, to display keyboard shortcuts in a keyboardless context

However, the media query documentation doesn't seem to mention anything about this.

It's 2016, is this still impossible?

Comment: So why not target **desktops** only? It's *fair* to assume that only desktop / laptop users have physical keyboards

Comment: Media queries can only target **output** (screen, print) and size, or orientation... Not input. Hence the name, **media** query, not device query

Comment: @Paulie_D Well, there _are_ media types like "handheld", "braille", "tv" and so on, which do sound like devices, don't they.

Comment: @Paulie_D: "media" does actually refer to devices as a whole. See [HTML401](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.4), [CSS21](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#media-types). And [Media Queries 4 has media features for certain input methods](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-4/#mf-interaction).

Comment: @MrLister Yes, but those all refer to the way the **output** will be rendered. Not on how the **input** is received...but I see BoltClock has a more in-depth reply.

Comment: @Aziz Sounds good, but how does one do that?  The only thing I've seen is via screen size, but some people's tablets' displays have a higher resolution than my keyboard-attached, non-touch netbook.

Comment: @Kev this is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/mras62ud/3/ it's not ideal and would require a lot of research. I'm beginning to think that targeting desktops with pure CSS media query might be impossible with the ever-increasing tablet and retina displays. Another problem is devices like *Asus Transform Book* which is a tablet/laptop with detachable keyboard. **You might have better luck attempting to detect if the display is a touchscreen with JavaScript**.

Comment: @Aziz Fair enough.  I had considered detachable keyboards, and I guess even phones might have them, in which case I still don't want to render the shortcut due to lack of screen space.  So I guess I'd need to detect both keyboard presence and real screen size, although as I've found on a Windows Phone, you already need JS to do the latter thanks to their design decisions: http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html

Comment: @Kev: "and I guess even phones might have them" [Yup.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oi1B9fjVs4) (And you don't even need Continuum to use Bluetooth peripherals with a Windows 10 phone - you can use them directly with the phone on its own screen.) The article you link to, thankfully, no longer applies to Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 phones - it behaves like other mobile browsers wrt responsive design.

Comment: @BoldClock the phone in question is unfortunately WP8, where it does apply.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media Queries 4 does not provide any media features for determining whether a physical keyboard is attached. There's nothing stopping you from proposing such a feature for MQ4 or MQ5 over at the www-style mailing list, though keep in mind whether such a media feature would be easy for vendors to implement is another story.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what would make it hard to implement?

Comment: @Kev: Only people familiar with browser engines can answer that. My point is that there is no guarantee that the feature will be made a priority, or implemented at all.

Comment: Posted this suggestion to the CSSWG: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3871

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is no query in Media Queries 4 to identify the existence of a keyboard.
There are other new queries though that might be helpful.

In my own application I'm assuming that a keyboard exists when there is a mouse or a touchpad as primary input. You can query for that with

`@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) { ... }`

This query would go `false` for devices with a touchscreen, stylus devices and also exotic devices like camera input.

Note that with this query you're querying for primary input devices. You can query all input devices with 
`any-hover` and `any-pointer`.

Also note that as of date, the adoption for MQ4 is 81% of all browsers, but no Firefox: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-interaction

Comment: It's imaginable that there will one day (maybe soon, if apple pulls an apple, or if ever drawing tablets combine with leap-motions) be touch screens that support hovering, so this may lose its meaning one day. Seems a shame.